# trait bound `AccountInfo<'_>: BorshSerialize` was not satisfied

Tags: solana-program, rust

I'm trying to save AccountInfo in a struct that #[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Clone, Debug)] to send SOL to this account. Cuz this account is randomly chosen from a map in the contract so I cannot pass it into data to make instructions. This is the code:

```
#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct State<'a> {
    pub owner: AccountInfo<'a>,
}
```

But the compiler returned this error:

"trait bound `AccountInfo<'_>: BorshSerialize` was not satisfied"

So how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot send SOL to an account without providing that account to the runtime, alternatively what you can do is save the address in the state, then validate the provided owner is correct / do that verification directly on the account struct

```
#[account]
pub struct State {
    pub owner: Pubkey,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SomeTransfer<'info> {
    #[account(has_one = owner)]
    pub state: Account<'info, State>
    pub owner: AccountInfo<'info>,
    // more checks...

}
```